# ActivityNotFoundException while sending email from the application

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-emulator

I have written a code in which I am allowing user to *send order via email* to vendor [ShopOwner] along with their personal and cart item details, but here I am getting an

**error: Unfortunately App has Stopped**

*Logcat:*

```
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/html flg=0x1 (has clip) (has extras) }
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at com.version.bajrang.january.menu.ArrowsActivity$1.onClick(ArrowsActivity.java:105)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-30 17:56:14.605: E/AndroidRuntime(951):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

*Code:*

```
Intent messageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String aEmailList[] = { "rakesh@rocketmail.com" };   
messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);
messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
messageIntent.setType("text/html");
messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body.toString()));
startActivity(messageIntent);
```

Finally with the Help of SahilMahajanMj, I have used this code with little change:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"rakesh@rocketmail.com"});
 i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
 i.setType("message/rfc822");
 i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body.toString()));

try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send email via :"));
    Toast.makeText(ArrowsActivity.this, "Email Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(ArrowsActivity.this, "There are no email applications installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

In *ViewCartActivity.java*

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent mViewCartIntent = new Intent(ViewCartActivity.this, com.version.bajrang.january.menu.ArrowsActivity.class);
        mViewCartIntent.putExtra("name", myTextVeiwGrandTotal.getText().toString());
        startActivity(mViewCartIntent);

            }
        });
```

In *ArrowsActivity.java:*

```
TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
Intent i = getIntent();
String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
txtName.setText(name);
```

I am using above code to get total number of products in cart and i am able to get and show as well, but here total number of items in cart i also want to show on cart tab like:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.queppelin.tastykhana

they have shown 2 in red...

Comment: Post your `AndroidManifest.xml` too.

Comment: You might want to choose less general question names in the future. ;)

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, I have changed the title of your question to provide some meaning to it. feel free to edit, if it doesnt suites the purpose.

Comment: @SiddharthLele i posted AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Rakesh See my answer, I think it will help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The error message shows:

> ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/html flg=0x1 (has clip) (has
>   extras) }

It means that the android system doesnt found any email sending activity to handle the intent created by you. Make sure you have email application installed in your device.

Also use the following code to send email,

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail"));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email applications installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: brother in my earlier version i have used same code to send email along with details, few days ago it was working fine and now i have seen i am getting same problem there big big trouble for me...please help

Comment: have you checked that whether you have email application installed in your device.?

Comment: Thanks bhaiya i have replaced this i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);with i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body.toString())); and it has worked...

Comment: please help me like you did earlier, i also want to number of items in cart on Tab like here they have show 2 in red color: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.queppelin.tastykhana  and i have posted my code and edited my code please check above...

Comment: @Rakesh I am not getting what the issue is. Can you please put it as a separate question and share the link here.

Comment: brother please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623595/way-to-badge-android-tab-view-at-runtime  and if possible so this one also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621749/list-of-all-upcoming-facebook-friends-birthdays-in-android

Answer (score 6):

Rakesh sorry for late reply, since 10 am i was trying to resolve your issue and i have tried several times and finally below code has worked:

i knew you got answer, but i have given many hours for my satisfaction i am placing my answer here, and brother i don't need points for this, because @SahilMahajanMj deserve this:

```
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"rakesh@rocketmail.com"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        i.setType("message/rfc822");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body.toString()));

        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send email via :"));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(ArrowsActivity.this, "There are no email applications installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: thanks for support : God Bless You, i can't tick on right, but i wish to give you points what you deserve..thanks again..

Answer (score 3):

Seem problem with `android.content` which you passing with your `putExtras` .

try something like below:

```
public Intent sendMail1() {
        Intent messageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        String aEmailList[] = { "rakesh@rocketmail.com" };
        messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);

        messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

        messageIntent.setType("text/html");
        messageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                Html.fromHtml(body.toString()));

        return messageIntent;
    }
```

Fire your intent like:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendMail1(), "send mail"));
```