# List of all Upcoming Facebook Friends Birthdays in Android

Tags: facebook, android-facebook

How to get *Facebook Friends Birthdays in order of upcoming* like: show **top on list those birthdays are coming next** by using current date and so on.

still i am getting birthdays in form of January to December, Getting Friends on Top those birthdays in January and on bottom those birthdays in December.

and i am also *getting friends on top those birthdays has gone in January like birthday was on 2nd Jan or 28 Jan*,

Now i just want to see *list of Next Upcoming Birthdays*,those passed away on bottom of the list...

Like here:

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/birthday-sweet-birthday-calendar/id367346406?mt=8

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scoompa.birthdayreminder&hl=en

they have shown recents on top and later on bottom in a List...

Still i am using this query :

```
    String query = "select name, birthday, uid, pic_square from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) order by birthday_date";
```

Also Tried with this code:

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;

    String query = "select name, birthday, uid, pic_square from user where uid in " +
    "(select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())AND birthday_date >= '" + month + "/01' AND birthday_date <= '" + month + "/31' ORDER BY birthday_date ASC";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list of friends according to their birthday. like,

```
SELECT uid, name, birthday_date FROM user
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
AND birthday_date >= CURRENT_DATE
AND birthday_date <= LAST_DATE
ORDER BY birthday_date ASC
```

Here in place of `CURRENT_DATE` you could enter the current system date. So this will show the upcoming birthday from the current date. and in place of `LAST_DATE`, you could use the date upto which you want to show the upcoming birthdays.

Comment: buddy i have tried with this: Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
  int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
  
  String query = "select name, birthday, uid, pic_square from user where uid in " +
  "(select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())AND birthday_date >= '" + month + "/01' AND birthday_date <= '" + month + "/31' ORDER BY birthday_date ASC";  but not getting any list...

Comment: So, what you are getting in the **month** variable.? Is it **2(February)**.? Do you know february doesnt have any **31 Date**.? Are you sure, you have some friends whose birthday falls in between **1 February** to the date you have used.?

Comment: i am not getting list of friends even, please tell me what i should write and where i am doing mistake need help buddy..

Comment: @Rakesh, Dont panic, first check that what value you are getting in the **month** variable. try printing some **Log** to check its value.

Comment: thanks again for fast reply, ok buddy i will try that and then get back to you, for now thanks again...