# Email intent not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I had this in my `onOptionItemSelected` of menu. Whenever I try to run this intent it throws force close error.

```
case R.id.Mail:
    Intent emailIntent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,message);
    startActivity(emailIntent);
    break;
```

Comment: what is the exception you get?

Comment: i dont what exception but when i select EMail option from my menu my app gets force close.

Comment: logcat doesn't print anything?

Comment: activity not found exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604349/activitynotfoundexception-while-sending-email-from-the-application

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it might help you..

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"abc@gmail.com"});        
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sunject Text Here..");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
email.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send Mail Using :"));
```

Comment: its show some dialog box saying:"No apllication can perform this action"

Comment: yes, it opens Email and Gmail and etc options. you can use default configured email account to send mail using this dialog box. and once this dialog will open, just select checkbox ( at bottom of that dialog  ) to set this as default. then it will not open any dialog again. :)

Comment: yeah this might work for me but can u tell me how can i setup E-Mail app in my emulator??

Comment: Thanks its working. can u explain this "email.setType("message/rfc822");" and vote for my question.

Comment: ya sure, "email.setType("message/rfc822")" will set the SMTP/MIME type of this email intent. and a Content-Type "message/rfc822" indicates that the body contains an encapsulated message, with the syntax of an RFC 822 message.

Answer (score 0):

try to use it like that

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(); 
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    intent.setType("plain/text");
    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,  new String[]{address});
    return intent;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.May be you have to check that your email is register in you android mobile email application.You have to create one id in your mobile email application.

```
case R.id.Mail:
    Intent emailIntent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,message);
    startActivity(emailIntent);
    break;
```